# Create a functor in CUDA with a static __global__ function as executor

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, gpu, variadic-templates

I have a design in C++ where I can compile time generate function calls for templated functions based on an `std::integer_sequence`. This works for CPU, but I would like to extend this to GPU using CUDA. However, I am not allowed to put a `__global__` function into a `struct`. Is there another way to achieve what I am trying to do?

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

struct Functor_cpu
{
    template<int I>
    static void exec(int* __restrict__ data, const int itot)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<itot; ++i)
            data[i] *= I;
    }
};

struct Functor_gpu
{
    template<int I> __global__
    static void exec(int* __restrict__ data, const int itot)
    {
        const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

        if (i < itot)
            data[i] *= I;
    }
};

template<class Func, class... Args, int... Is>
void test(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>, Args... args)
{
    (Func::template exec<Is>(args...), ...);
}

template<class Func, class... Args, int... Is>
void test_gpu(const int problem_size, std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>, Args... args)
{
    dim3 grid{problem_size/64 + (problem_size%64 > 0)}, block{64};
    (Func::template exec<Is><<<grid, block>>>(args...), ...);
}

int main()
{
    const int itot = 1024;

    // CPU
    std::vector<int> data_cpu(itot);
    test<Functor_cpu>(std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3, 4>{}, data_cpu.data(), itot);

    // GPU.
    int* data_gpu;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &data_gpu, itot*sizeof(int));

    dim3 block{64};
    dim3 grid{itot/block.x + (itot%block.x > 0)};
    test_gpu<Functor_gpu>(itot, std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3, 4>{}, data_gpu);

    cudaFree(data_gpu);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not wrap every __global__ function in a normal host function?

Comment: Can you post an answer? I do not fully see how do deal with the templates here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not allowed to put a `__global__` function into a struct.

Correct.

> Is there another way to achieve what I am trying to do?

I don't think you have completely spelled out what you are trying to do.  For example, I assume you may have other functions besides multiplying by a compile time constant as you have shown here.  However I think one possible approach to get past the obstacle you have identified is to:

1. Put the `__global__` function definition at global scope (since this is basically required, we may as well start here), rather than part of a class/struct, templated for the functionality you want to implement.
2. Pass the functionality you want to implement via a template parameter, contained in a functor.

Here is a rough example:

```
$ cat t58.cu
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

struct f_mult
{
    template <typename T>
    __host__ __device__
    void operator ()(T *d, T I, int i) { d[i] = d[i]*I;}
};

struct f_div
{
    template <typename T>
    __host__ __device__
    void operator ()(T *d, T I, int i) { d[i] = d[i]/I;}
};

struct f_saxpy
{
    template <typename T>
    __host__ __device__
    void operator ()(T *x, T y, T a, int i) {x[i] = a*x[i]+y;}
};
template<class f, int I>
static void exec_cpu(int* __restrict__ data, const int itot)
{
    f my_F;
    for (int i=0; i<itot; ++i)
        my_F(data, I, i);
}

template<class f, int I, class... Args> __global__
void exec_gpu(const int itot, Args... args)
{
    const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    f my_F;
    if (i < itot)
        my_F(args..., I, i);
};

template<class Func, class... Args, int... Is>
void test(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>, Args... args)
{
    (exec_cpu<Func, Is>(args...), ...);
}

template<class Func, class... Args, int... Is>
void test_gpu(const int problem_size, std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>, Args... args)
{
    dim3 grid(problem_size/64 + (problem_size%64 > 0)), block(64);
    (exec_gpu<Func, Is><<<grid, block>>>(problem_size, args...), ...);
}

int main()
{
    const int itot = 1024;

    // CPU
    std::vector<int> data_cpu(itot);
    test<f_mult>(std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3, 4>{}, data_cpu.data(), itot);

    // GPU.
    int* data_gpu;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &data_gpu, itot*sizeof(int));
    int y = 7;
    test_gpu<f_mult>(itot, std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3, 4>{}, data_gpu);
    test_gpu<f_div> (itot, std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3, 4>{}, data_gpu);
    test_gpu<f_saxpy> (itot, std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 3, 4>{}, data_gpu, y);

    cudaFree(data_gpu);

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t58 t58.cu -std=c++17
$ cuda-memcheck ./t58
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvprof ./t58
==55176== NVPROF is profiling process 55176, command: ./t58
==55176== Profiling application: ./t58
==55176== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   16.19%  2.1760us         1  2.1760us  2.1760us  2.1760us  _Z8exec_gpuI6f_multLi2EJPiEEviDpT1_
                   11.43%  1.5360us         1  1.5360us  1.5360us  1.5360us  _Z8exec_gpuI6f_multLi3EJPiEEviDpT1_
                   10.48%  1.4080us         1  1.4080us  1.4080us  1.4080us  _Z8exec_gpuI7f_saxpyLi4EJPiiEEviDpT1_
                   10.48%  1.4080us         1  1.4080us  1.4080us  1.4080us  _Z8exec_gpuI6f_multLi4EJPiEEviDpT1_
                   10.48%  1.4080us         1  1.4080us  1.4080us  1.4080us  _Z8exec_gpuI5f_divLi3EJPiEEviDpT1_
                   10.24%  1.3760us         1  1.3760us  1.3760us  1.3760us  _Z8exec_gpuI5f_divLi2EJPiEEviDpT1_
                   10.24%  1.3760us         1  1.3760us  1.3760us  1.3760us  _Z8exec_gpuI7f_saxpyLi2EJPiiEEviDpT1_
                   10.24%  1.3760us         1  1.3760us  1.3760us  1.3760us  _Z8exec_gpuI7f_saxpyLi3EJPiiEEviDpT1_
                   10.24%  1.3760us         1  1.3760us  1.3760us  1.3760us  _Z8exec_gpuI5f_divLi4EJPiEEviDpT1_
      API calls:   90.99%  263.81ms         1  263.81ms  263.81ms  263.81ms  cudaMalloc
                    4.85%  14.073ms         8  1.7591ms  1.0394ms  2.2642ms  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    3.68%  10.668ms       808  13.203us     200ns  970.67us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.35%  1.0199ms         8  127.49us  85.773us  170.92us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.09%  256.61us         1  256.61us  256.61us  256.61us  cudaFree
                    0.02%  67.286us         9  7.4760us  4.2950us  27.253us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.01%  24.842us         8  3.1050us  1.0410us  5.0730us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  8.6170us        16     538ns     214ns  1.8110us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  3.9830us         8     497ns     254ns  1.0350us  cuDeviceGetUuid
                    0.00%  3.4770us         3  1.1590us     697ns  1.9520us  cuDeviceGetCount
$
```

I've updated the GPU code from a previous version, to show how different functor "prototypes" can be handled, without any change to the overall dispatch structure.

Comment: This is a great solution. I have used this method to achieve what I wanted to do.